Run entire query with selection highlighted in SSMS
Is there any way that you can always execute the entire script/query you have open in SSMS when you click the 'Execute' button, rather than executing simply the portion you have highlighted? This hasn't been a problem for me yet, more just an annoyance, but I just realized (when I went to update a stored procedure) that I had only some comments selected. It looked like the query executed successfully, but that was because it was only executing the ignored comments. If I didn't catch it, I could have lost data from the SP that I thought was saved to the database.
In this case, it wasn't an issue, since I caught it right away and nothing broke by executing just the comments, but I'm a little bit worried that I might accidentally, say, run a portion of a query that would cause something to break if you only run that part, maybe something destructive like an UPDATE or DELETE, and not notice.
From what I can gather, I don't think this is possible. I am on SSMS version 20.1.10.0.

No. The whole reason for highlighting is so you can execute just that section. Click once anywhere in the query window to remove the highlighting.

Hmm, I wish there was an option for that, couldn't hurt. I guess this is a pretty niche use case though. I had a similar issue in VS 2022. They added multi-row tabs, which are GREAT (I use them 24/7), but then instead of giving the option to scroll through tabs with the scroll wheel, as requested, they instead made it so that scrolling on the tabs toggles multi-row tabs on and off (which also messes up your tab order). You can't disable it. I know the options are pretty cluttered already, but it would be nice to have the ability to toggle more features on and off.
